# Code works but test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd, shoulda

I have a test that's failing even though the operation actually works when I test it in the browser. Something wrong with my test, looks like.

I'm using Shoulda and fixtures.

```
require 'test_helper'

class AddressesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context 'on PUT to :update' do
    setup do
      put(:update, {
          :id => addresses(:mary_publics_address).id,
          :street1 => '123 Now St.'
        }, { :user_id => users(:stan).id})
    end
    should 'update the Address' do
      a = Address.find(addresses(:mary_publics_address).id)
      assert(a.street1 == '123 Now St.', 'Attribute did not get updated.')
    end
  end
end
```

Fails with "Attribute did not get updated."

Here is the controller code under test:

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    @address.update_attributes!(params[:address])
    render(:text => "Address with ID #{params[:id]} updated")
  end
end
```

Comment: "Code works but test fails". That's exactly my first thought when the test-team calls :P

Comment: what does a.street1 come back with?

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment; I am asking what a.street1 actually comes back with, not just what the assumption is.  As someone that tests, printing out the expected value and the actual value from a test can be very insightful.

Comment: OK, printed it. Comes back with original value that was supposed to be replaced. ("100 East San Marcos Blvd., Suite 412")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a params[:address] specified in the parameters you are passing to your action in the test. It looks to me like it should be:

```
put(:update, {
        :id => addresses(:mary_publics_address).id,
        :address => { :street1 => '123 Now St.' }
      }, { :user_id => users(:stan).id})
```

I suspect your `street1` address field is named correctly in your form as `address[street1]` which is why it is working via the browser.